# Got a google AIY Authorization Error while trying to connect to google cloud

Tags: google-assistant-sdk, google-assist-api, google-ai-platform, google-aiy, google-assistant

I was at the `cd ~/AIY-projects-python/src/examples/voice ./assistant_library_demo.py`

part, after i got the link and pasted it into the browser i got this error:

`Error 403: access_denied The developer hasn’t given you access to this app. It’s currently being tested and it hasn’t been verified by Google. If you think you should have access, contact the developer`

Keep in mind that i am logged in the account that i just got the api from. Is not like i am on another one...so..what can i do ?

Comment: Responded on your github issue. Please check : https://github.com/google/aiyprojects-raspbian/issues/719#issuecomment-740399638

Comment: If you have a solution, please post it *as an answer*, with details. After an enforced delay, you'll also be able to *accept* the answer, which is how we know that questions have been dealt with here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution to this is to add your e-mail address as a tester. Click OAuth Consent Screen in the left menu, then click the Add Users button under "Test Users".

Comment: I forgot about this question. All i had to do was publish my app..